# How can I turn off the tutorial popups?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm over 20 hours into my game, but I still get popups telling me what Assassinations are, describing Vehicle Thefts, telling me about upgrades when I level, etc. I've already participated in all of these activities.

I've searched the ingame options screen, and I've found no way to turn off these annoying tutorial/help popups. Is there some option I've somehow overlooked? Or am I stuck with these?

For reference, I'm playing the Xbox 360 version, so I cannot install any mods or edit any files for the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't yet found any way to do so, and unfortunately, I can confirm that even people who've beaten the game experience the same issue. The paucity of configurables in general is a disappointment, but this one especially grates. It would be nice to think that a future update will include this, but if it's even added, it will probably be through DLC.

Comment: Ergh, this is disappointing to hear.